# CocoaPods link_with

Tags: cocoapods

i am trying to include different libraries for different targets.

```
link_with 'Target 1', 'Target 2', 'Target 3'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 1.1.1'

link_with 'Target 4', 'Target 5'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 1.1.1'
```

How to do that?

**Solution**
(Thanks to SalvoC for solution!)

```
target :'Main App', :exclusive => true do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
  pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 1.1.1'

  platform :ios, '8.0'
  pod 'SplunkMint'
end

target :'Main App Extension', :exclusive => true do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 1.1.1'
end
```

When changing target configuration in Podfile, assure you removed all previously generated *.a files. They persist for every target and you get the error about the "duplicates" when you build.

If you changed "Other Linker Flages" manually, before running pod install, make sure you remove the old entries and put in the $(inherited).

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use link_with in this case.
Try this:

```
target :'Target 1', :exclusive => true do
   platform :ios, '7.0'
   pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 1.1.1'
end
```

and specify the statements for each of your target

Comment: this doesn't work if i have the same library in "Main Target" and in "Extension", i am getting "ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"

Comment: Can you please add some detail?  Sounds like you are misusing the _exclusive_ clause. Can you post your podfile with the fixes I suggested and that is not working?

Comment: i had to remove some linker flags and old *.a files. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

[Cocoapods 1.0](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0/) has removed link_with & exclusive => true in favour of abstract_target.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Qiulang, **abstract_target** is now the way to link multiple pods with multiple targets:

```
abstract_target 'someNameForAbstractTarget' do
  pod 'podThatIsForAllTargets'
end

target 'realTarget' do
  pod 'podThatIsOnlyForThisTarget'
end
```